# Staying up to date in AI, Machine Learning and Data Mining

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, computer-science, data-mining

I'm currently finishing my Master and I probably won't be joining the academic ranks. I really like Machine Learning, Data Mining, AI in general. 
How can I stay up to date with all the new research? Should I subscribe to a Journal? Maybe IEEE or ACM? I don't mind reading papers at all, but it seems like a lot of published papers are accessible only in academia.

How do you stay up to date in this fields?

Comment: You are more likely to get a response at places like: http://www.reddit.com/r/machinelearning, SO is about programming problems.

Comment: Plenty of articles can be found on authors homepages for free, via Google...

Comment: http://arxiv.org/ - select your relevant topics and check daily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides a rich bank of free papers on the web there are a lot of website providing the state-of-the-art artificial intelligence courses which are fun to take and learn such as [MIT open courseware](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/) and moocs such as [coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) which is the most fun and enjoyable resourse in the web.